# Is there any possibility to add self-extracting resources to an firemonkey-built .apk-file?

Tags: android, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I would like to simply add an image in `TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath` by installing the .apk.

Is there maybe any built-in option to do so with RAD Studio XE7?

All I did by now is manually copied the needed resources to the destination folder and then installed the apk. But this is no option in practice.

Comment: What should happen if someone deletes the image from the SharedDocuments path?

Comment: Well the SharedDocuments path on android is imho something like /storage/emulated/0/android/data/com.embarcadero.Project1/ so it's unlikely that someone will delete resources by mistake from this location.

Comment: But of course the app should throw an error if this happens, to answer your question.

Comment: You are right the documents folders are bound to the application. Did you have a look at the docs? Especially [this chapter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Creating_an_Android_App) (go to **Loading and Deploying Files**)?

Comment: I did now. Thank You for the link, it was totally what I was looking for. If you want to post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Well actually the documentation is wrong and incomplete. You must include the trailing backslash for the path and you must not add files for all configurations (add them explicit for debug or release) otherwise the files are not included